# Roots of polynomial $\sum_{k = 0}^{n} \sqrt{\binom{n}{k}} x^k = 0$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

I'm interested in roots of the polynomial $$p(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \sqrt{\binom{n}{k}}  x^k = 0$$

I've looked around but can't find anything in the literature or forums. Since coefficients are all real, roots come in complex conjugate pairs. Having looks at some solutions for specific values of $n$ I also conjecture that for certain values of $n$ all roots lie on $|x| = 1$, but have no idea how to approach this (eg for $n=11$ all but 2 roots lie on the unit circle). Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I just make a check. Let's $(n,m)$ be the degree number of the polynomial and the numbers of roots that lies on $|x| = 1$
$$(n,m) = (10,10), (11,7),(15,11), (21,17), (25,17),(28,20),(35,23),\color{red}{(40,4)},(50,34)$$
Then, perhaps the question should be: *prove there are roots lie on $|x| = 1$* and/or *count the number of roots that lies on $|x| = 1$*

Comment: For any palindromic real polynomial, it can be rigorously shown that either the roots are on the unit circle (when the complex conjugate is also the reciprocal of the root), or there are sets of $4$ roots of form $\alpha, \overline \alpha, \frac1\alpha, \frac1{\overline \alpha}$that do not lie on the unit circle.  Thus you can see in the post above, $ 4 \mid (n-m)$.  The specific coefficients here do not seem to contribute much to the understanding of for which $n$ we may have non-unit-circle roots.

Comment: @Macavity Very interesting. You should transform your comment into an answer. (and give a reference if it is possible)

Comment: @JeanMarie Just an observation, not quite an answer yet, so waiting.  As $n$ increases, there seem to be more points not on the unit circle than otherwise.

Comment: @NN2 I get $(40, 28)$ not $(40, 4)$ - maybe some numerical stability issue.  $m/n$ seems to be "smooth" in some sense, and non-increasing, as I observe.

Comment: @Macavity I used Mathematica with the function Solve. With the function NSolve, I obtain different result $(40,28)$.

Comment: Another finding: Let's $(n,k)$ be degree number of the polynomial and the numbers of roots that **don't** lie on $|x|=1$. Then $k$ increases by $4$ with $n$ begins by $11,22,33,45,57,68$. For example: $$n=11,...,21 \implies k = 4$$
$$n=22,...,32 \implies k = 8$$
$$n=33,...,44 \implies k = 12$$
$$... n=57,...,67 \implies k = 20 ...$$

Answer (score 4):

**This isn't an answer** but some remarks that can help for making conjectures.

Let $$p_n(x) := \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \sqrt{\binom{n}{k}}  x^k $$

The fact that the non-real roots of many polynomials are **close to** the unit circle has been remarked and studied many times for example [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/182412), but here they are **on** the unit circle but some "outsiders" (or "insiders" :)) (see graphical representation below).

But $p_n$ has the property of being a **self-reciprocal** (or palindromic) polynomial:

$$x^{n}p_n(\tfrac1x)=p_n(x) \tag{1}$$

The fact that the roots of such polynomials can be all on the unit circle has been studied, for example [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.2953.pdf), but we are here in a case where a  few of them are not on it...

[image]

*Fig. 1: The roots are the little red points with the index of their resp. polynomials. You will find for example 5 roots labelled "5".*

Some elementary remarks:

1. The roots come by conjugate pairs because the coefficients of $p_n$ are real.
2. Root $-1$ is common to all $p_n$ with $n$ odd, precisely because $p_n$ is a self reciprocal polynomial : indeed take $x=-1$ in (1).

Comment: Hi, Jean, interesting remarks

Comment: Hi, @G Cab, indeed a captivating issue...

Comment: I just found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/258713) this integral representation 
$p_n(1)=\sum_{k=0}^n\sqrt{\binom{n}k}
=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_C\sqrt{g(z)}\,\pi\cot(\pi z)\,dz$ (which is fact classical for establishing a bridge: sums $\leftrightarrow$ integrals). Couldn't it be extended to $p_n(x)$ by introducing $x$ as a supplementary parameter ?

Comment: ahi .. unfortunately residue theorem is not my stronghold .. I cannot be of much help